# C# WebApi - Asp Net Core 2 - How can I put the csproj name into the route programmatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Edit: To be clear, I dont actually care if its the csproj.  I just want to be able to globally define a root name for all my routes.

I am new to dotnet core 2 and c# in general.  I am building a webapi template for the rest of my team to use, but I want to be able to put the csproj name as part of the route so people dont have to change it in every controller.

So for example:

```
WebStoreAbc.csproj
--------

[Route("api/v1/#CSPROJNAME#/products")]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
  ... controller logic ...
}


Registers at runtime as:
/api/v1/WebStoreAbc/products
```

This way, I dont have to configure routes for a bunch of controllers everytime I make a new project from the template.

Edit 2: I used Mahmoud Heretani's answer below and tweaked it.

```
string projectName = "template";

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "api/v1/" + projectName.ToLower() + "/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: you should host them separately.

Comment: or have a look at areas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It think that you cannot insert a variable inside [Route] attribute, because it required a constant value, however a simple trick inside your Configure method should do the trick:

```
 var projectName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name;

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "api/v1/" + projectName + "/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

But in your case, I would recommend that you create an assembly (class library) contains a method to configure the route using the assembly name (just like the previous example), and then use this method across your projects.

Comment: This is great.  I edited my original post to show what I did.